# How to implement Jquery Text Editor with Hindi Language?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, hindi

I have to put Text Editor with Hindi Language typing in my Project.
I have used following text editor in my project:- 
"http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor"

But the problem is that i am not able to enable Hindi Language writing in that text editor.
I have some modifications in it but the result was the same. 
So,is there any way to enable Hindi language writing in the above linked text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide users with some input method to enter Hindi in that text editor like a virtual keyboard.

Or if user has something like Google IME for Hindi (It is a desktop application) then user can type Hindi in the text editor.

So you can not just depend on Google IME for Hindi, hence you need to come up with some virtual keyboard. You can also search for some ready made virtual keyboards over internet.

Comment: As far as I know you can not. Fonts are just graphical representations. You need to take particular Unicode for Hindi characters as an input from the user to show Hindi characters. That's why you need to use virtual keyboard.